# Using R with Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, heroku

I'm working on getting our Rails application talking to R using [rserve server](http://rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html) and the [rserve-simpler](https://github.com/jtprince/rserve-simpler) gem.

Everything works fine locally when I load my app, but in Heroku, my rails app is unable to make a connection to rserve, even though the worker successfully started on deploy.

```
app[web.1]: Rserve::Connection::RserveNotStartedError (Can't start Rserve):
```

Below are the details of my configuration.

**.buildpacks**

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git#cedar-14
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
rserve: R -f rserve.r --gui-none --no-save
```

**rserve.r**

```
require('Rserve')

# get the port allowed
port <- Sys.getenv('PORT')

# run Rserve in process
run.Rserve(debug = TRUE, port, args = NULL, config.file = "./rserve.conf")
```

**rserve.conf**

```
remote enable
```

As you can see, rails is running on one dynco and rserver is running on another dyno in heroku.

I suspect that because rserve is running on a different dyno, rails can't talk to rserve using the default connection parameters, but I'm not sure how or even if I could fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
From [Heroku on Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos):

> Dynos execute in complete isolation from one another, even when on the
>   same physical infrastructure.

This is re-enforcing my suspicions that it won't be possible to have rails make a connection to rserve running into a different dyno.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you look into websockets or message-queues (eg. RabbitMQ)? As this is a way to communicate between dynos (web <> worker).